# Opening a WPF popup on button click

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, popupwindow

I have a WPF button and I am trying to show a WPF popup over it, or at its top, when button is clicked:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="3">
    <Button x:Name="btnPrint"
        FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" 
        Style="{DynamicResource MyButtonStyle}"  
        Margin="15 5 5 5" Height="29"
        IsEnabled="{Binding BtnPrintEnabled}" 
        Command="{Binding btnPrintCommand}" 
        IsTabStop="False">
        Print
    </Button>
    <Popup IsOpen="{Binding IsPrintPopupOpen}" StaysOpen="False"  >
        <Border Background="LightYellow">
            <TextBlock>Sending to print ...</TextBlock>
        </Border>
    </Popup>
</StackPanel>
```

Popup is bound to a property in view model so when button is clicked, button command is executed. Command executes below method in view model:

```
private void ImprimirRemesa()
{
   IsPrintPopupOpen = true;

   // Do some things

   IsPrintPopupOpen = false;
}

private bool _isPrintPopupOpen = false;
public bool IsPrintPopupOpen
{
    get
    {
        return _isPrintPopupOpen;
    }

    set
    {
        if (_isPrintPopupOpen = value) return;

        _isPrintPopupOpen = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("IsPrintPopupOpen");
    }
}
```

but it does not work. Nothing happens.

Comment: if(_isPrintPopupOpen == value)  are you missing '=' or its just a typo

Comment: How do you change the value of IsPrintPopupOpen?

Comment: "Nothing happens" as in the `ImprimirRemesa()` method is not called or "nothing happens" as in the popup not being displayed?

Comment: @tabby Yes, you are right. This was the problem.

Comment: @Babbillumpa As shown in the code, I do an assignment, IsPrintPopupOpen = true.

Comment: @mm8 Method is called. When I say nothing happens I mean popup is not being shown. The problem was I was doing if(_isPrintPopupOpen = value) instead of if(_isPrintPopupOpen == value)

Comment: @Babbillumpa Because it's valid code - it's a logic error rather than a compilation error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new wpf project.

Add a nuget reference too https://www.nuget.org/packages/RelayCommand to leverage RelayCommand.

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Documents.DocumentStructures;
using System.Windows.Input;
using ButtonPopup.View.ViewModel;

namespace ButtonPopup
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = new DataContextObject();
        }
    }

    public class DataContextObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool _isPrintPopupOpen;

        public bool IsPrintPopupOpen
        {
            get { return _isPrintPopupOpen; }

            set
            {
                if (_isPrintPopupOpen == value)
                {
                    return;
                }

                _isPrintPopupOpen = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsPrintPopupOpen));
            }
        }

        public ICommand PrintCommand => new RelayCommand(InitiatePrint);

        private async void InitiatePrint(object obj)
        {
            IsPrintPopupOpen = true;

            await Task.Delay(3000);

            IsPrintPopupOpen = false;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="btnPrint"
            Margin="15 5 5 5" Height="29"
            Command="{Binding PrintCommand}" 
            IsTabStop="False">
        Print
    </Button>
    <Popup IsOpen="{Binding IsPrintPopupOpen}" StaysOpen="False" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=btnPrint}" >
        <Border Background="LightYellow">
            <TextBlock>Sending to print ...</TextBlock>
        </Border>
    </Popup>
</Grid>
```

Visual representation:

[image]

Comment: Very nice example!